# Excel Replacing Cell formatting with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

OK so i would like to figure out a way to change the cells within the worksheet behind the scenes of Excel 2007 with VBA so if i have something in Cell A1 and B1 then C1 will automatically populate a answer without having any formulas in the box.

i tried

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
dim weekCost as integer
dim monthCost as integer
dim salesTax as integer
dim totalCost as integer

weekCost = Range("$A$1")
monthCost = Range("$B$2")

salesTax = (weekCost + monthCost) * .08
totalCost = weekCost + monthCost

totalCost = salesTax + totalCost

totalCost = range("$C$1")

end sub
```

I cant get the totalcost to stick to that cell any one know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment statement is backwards, try:

```
Range("C1") = totalCost
```

Comment: No problem. Do consider marking the answer as "Accepted" if it's solved your problem :)

Comment: where is this option located?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious fix is to change the last line to `range("$C$1").Value = totalCost`.

If that doesn't work, here are some other things to consider:

1. One immediate issue I see with the code is that the Worksheet_Change sub should actually be defined as `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
2. Make sure that the function is *in the code page of the specific worksheet where you want the event to be captured*.  If you put it into a regular code module it will not be called.
3. Another issue you may want to address is that right now the code would recalculate every time that *any* cell is modified, not just A1 or B1.  You can put the code inside an If statement to limit when the recalculation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Or 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,1).Value = totalCost